# can't select a options from my react-boostrap select element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I tried many ways to select some options from the select, but it didn't work. Could you help to solve my problem, please? When I do a console.log, the selected options change, but the frontend doesn't show it. It keeps the default option "Select the option." I am using react-bootstrap and firebase. I don't know what the error is. I was thinking about the browser, but it is not the problem.

```
class Formm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      detail: "",
      cost: 0,
      category: ""
    };
    this.setCategory = this.setCategory.bind(this);
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  setCategory = (e) => {
    let index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value});
    console.log(e.target.value)
  };
render() {
    const { detail, cost, category } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <FirebaseDatabaseProvider firebase={firebase} {...firebaseConfig}>
          <FirebaseDatabaseNode path="category/">
            {(data) => {
              const { value } = data;
              if (value === null || typeof value === "undefined") return null;
              const values = Object.values(value);
              return <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label htmlFor="">Insert the type:</label>
                  <select
                    onChange={this.setCategory}
                    value={category}
                    className="form-control"
                  >
                    <option value={null}>Select the option</option>
                    {values.map((value) => {
                      return (
                        <option key={value} value={value}>
                          {value}
                        </option>
                      );
                    })}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>;
            }}
          </FirebaseDatabaseNode>
        </FirebaseDatabaseProvider>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you’re using “this” keyword inside of an arrow function that your set state doesn’t run.

“this” refers to the Class itself, but an arrow function, unlike a standard function, has no reference to the Class even though it’s defined within the Class.

Fortunately there’s an easy fix:
If you change setCategory to a function using the function keyword your code will run as you expect.

Comment: Thank for your answer.. I did the thing you wrote, however, it is continuing with the same problem and worst, because, now the select element is show blocked and i can not select one item...

Comment: Can you send code sandbox?

Comment: ` setCategoria (e) {
    let index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    setState({ e: selectedCategoria.target.value});
    console.log(e.target.value)
  };` I got a error and It says no defined setState

Comment: You’re missing “this” keyword now, add it in.

Comment: also with 'this' is not selecting the item.. it is continuing with the default value 'Select a category'

Comment: It is selecting but dont change en the option element, only witn console.log.

Comment: I just realized, you also have a return inside render(), I have been using React for about 5 years and I have never seen that. I think that could be a potential issue.

Comment: Delete “if”, it’s outer curly braces, and the body of the statement. Keep the conditions within the parenthesis, move it right before your outermost div, and put ‘&&’ between them. 
‘’’
!(//your if condition logic) && <div>‘’’

If this is the case I’ll update my initial answer.